# Counting the number of registers by field of a CSV without using Pandas or Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file where I have all the registers that I have to manipulate. I have to count the number of registers by age field.
For example: 31: 6, 32: 5 and so on.
So I made this to turn the file into a dictionary, but I don't know how to search on the dict by a specific field and the code below is resulting on a error.

```py
counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for item['age'] in reader:
        counter['age'] += 1

print(counter)
```

```sh
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
```

**-- Updates --**
I resolved to change the read to a DictReader. Now my code is like that:

```py
counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for item in reader:
        if(item['age']):
            counter['person ' + str(item['age'])] += 1

print(sorted(counter['age'))
```

But using the sorted function I got a error of `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I can't use Numpy or Pandas to get the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem of ordering the dict with the sorted function and list comprehension using tuples (key, value).

```py
counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for item in reader:
        if item['age']:
            counter[item['age']] += 1

sorted_dict = sorted((key, value) for (key, value) in counter.items())
print(sorted_dict)
```

This method consists in the use of list comprehension and the sorted function on the tuples made of (key, value) allowing us to sort the dictionary by the key.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for item in reader:
        counter[person] += 1

print(counter)
```

**Edit:**

Try:

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for item in reader:
        if str(item['age']):
            counter['person ' + str(item['age'])] += 1

print(sorted(counter['age']))
```

Comment: Gives the error `TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @IsacMoura Now?

Comment: Thanks. Your reply gave me the basis to understand how to do. I updated the question with the error with the sorted function